# Elasticsearch want to retrieve all nodes memory percentage

Tags: elasticsearch

I am able to get "os.mem.used_percent" by this way
curl -GET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/os".

But I need to get all nodes percent only. So, that I make automation script which check if percentage not goes beyond 90 and if then send the node name.

Is there any way to get only node name and its memory used percentage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do using python.

```
curl -X -GET "http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats/os" > es.json  

with open("es.json") as f:
    es = json.load(f)

memory_used_per_node = {}
nodes_memory = {}

for n in es["nodes"]:
    nodes_memory[n] = es["nodes"][n]["os"]["mem"]["used_percent"]

memory_used_per_node["nodes_memory"] = nodes_memory
memory_used_per_node["cluster_name"] = es["cluster_name"]
```